# How to control a movieclip from within another movieclip as3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have got two movieclips on the main timeline. First one is envelope_mc and second is bg_main. In envelope_mc timeline there is a button on 25th frame which plays ahead when clicked.

```
stop();

on_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playAhead);

function playAhead(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    play();
}
```

I have also got some animation on bg_main which I wan't to trigger on 30th frame (inside bg_main timeline) when button is clicked in envelope_mc timeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From anything added to the stage you're able to access the root timeline via:

```
MovieClip(root)
```

Meaning you can access your mentioned MovieClips like this:

```
MovieClip(root).envelope_mc;
MovieClip(root).bg_main;
```

Comment: But I have set the above code on specific frame inside movieclips timeline if I copy actionscript code on the main (stage) timeline how will it work?

Comment: This code will perform the same no matter how nested it is within other MovieClips, try it.

Comment: I'm getting this error:  TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at Flashphotographygallerywebsite7_fla::bg_1/frame25()

Comment: Did you add an import statement for flash.display.MovieClip?

Comment: I tried adding this code in bg_main timeline but its still giving same error #1010: stop();
import flash.display.MovieClip;
MovieClip(root).on_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playAhead);

function playAhead(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 play();
}

Comment: Solved at last.I had forgot to include envelope_mc <code>MovieClip(root).envelope_mc.on_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playAhead);<code>